# Error while migration TYPO3 extension from TYPO3 6.2.31 to 8

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Hi I'm in progress to migrate one of my TYPO3 extensions from TYPO3 6.2.31 to 8 LTS.

Now I got one unclear error. When I activate the extension all looks good, but when I refresh the view I got this error:

> 1351584844: An argument "key" or "id" has to be provided (More information)
>
> TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Exception thrown in file /var/www/html/typo3_src-8.7.19/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/TranslateViewHelper.php in line 133.

The error code references this page: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1351584844

I double checked all Views I do not have an issue with `f:translate key=""`

What can cause this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look in the TYPO3 log. You can get there from backend. Maybe the error is explained in more details.

Comment: No just the same message no more info

Comment: Enable all debug options? If you get a stack trace you could narrow down the problem more

Comment: just 10 mins ago I found the issue. extension key was b_z ... but foldername was b-z .... don't know Why ... but I found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Extension key was `b_z` ... but foldername was `b-z` .... don't know Why ... but I found it